# What is $path pseudo column? What is the use of it in Athena (Presto)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

What is exactly "$path" used for? I just ran "select "$path" from table limit 10", in athena it's showing the file path of S3 where data is pointed. But when i gave limit 10, it's showing same path 10 times, if i don't limit the statement it's scanning entire data. Can please someone expalin.

Answer (score 10):

`"$path"` is a pseudo-column which evaluates to the path of the source file given row comes from. This is provided by [Presto's Hive connector](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html). If you have a file with 100 rows, you will get same path 100 times.

If you want to get first ten *distinct* paths, you should try

```
select DISTINCT "$path" from table limit 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @piotr